# removeEventListener not working in UseEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby

My question may seems stupid but I searched the solution for days, tried multiple changes nothing works. Here it is:

I have a React component that uses a script to perform a parallax effect. I use an eventlistener so when I scroll on the component it fires the script. However, I would like to remove this eventlistener when I continue the scroll. The removeEventListener doesn't work so when I change page I got an error (because the script doesn't find the Div).

Here is my component (I removed the front code which works fine to just keep the logic):

```
const GridTextParallax = () => {

    //trigger the script when component appear on the page  
    const { trigger, inView } = useInView({
        threshold: [0, 0.8],
    });
    
    
    const parallax = (scrolling) => {       
        if (scrolling > 0) {
            //All the parallax logic that works perfect
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (inView) {
            document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
                var scrolling = // perform the logic to calculate the scrolling rate within the component;
                    parallax(scrolling)
            });
            return () => { window.removeEventListener('scroll', parallax); };
        } else {
            console.log("outside viewport")
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', parallax);
        }
    }, [inView]);


    return (
        <section id="layer" ref={trigger} >
            All the front end...
        </section>
    )
}

export default GridTextParallax
```

What did I miss?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the same instance of callback to both `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` for the listener to be removed. In your case you're passing an anonymous arrow function to `addEventListener` and `paralax` function to `removeEventListener`.

The solution is to write the callback into a variable and use it in both `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`:

```
const cb = () => {
  var scrolling = // perform the logic to calculate the scrolling rate within the component;
  parallax(scrolling)
}

addEventListener("scroll", cb)

return () => {
  removeEventListener("scroll", cb)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, indeed that was the issue. You made my day